# A lot of duplicates...no fdupes,i want to make a script

Tags: scripting, find, hashsum, uniq, duplicate-files

No fdup please..I want to make a script.

I have a lot of file duplicates,there are more than 200

I made ( is under construction )  a bash script which make

md5sum on every file,then with uniq i put the duplicate md5s on

another file,then again i check the duplicates and put the entire line

in a third final file.

Now the problem..i can remove one by one the dups.

But my question is: is possible to find only the dups and put on 4th file to delete safely?

This is the script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Script is "under construction"

# First we make the md5sum
find mp3 -type f -print0 |xargs -0 md5sum|tee firstfile.txt

# Then we find all the md5sum identical and put in secondfile.txt
sort +1rn -2 +0 -1 firstfile.txt |awk '{print $1}'|uniq -d > secondfile.txt


# then we extract from the secondfile and firstfile md5sum and name
while read line;do grep -i $line firstfile.txt;done  < secondfile.txt > thirdfinal.txt
```

Now the problem..thirdfinal.txt contains a lot of lines
similar to those

```
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/16.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/12.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/20.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/21.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/19.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/9.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/5.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/7.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/10.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/8.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/3.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/2.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/1.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/11.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/6.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/4.mp3
d7fbd596e86dfdb546092f34ab8ca576  mp3/25.mp3
d7fbd596e86dfdb546092f34ab8ca576  mp3/25.mp3
```

My question is...how to grep the third file to obtain

a 4th file which includes ALL duplicates..except the first

line(otherwise you delete ALL file including the original!)

So you can have a line of duplicates but at the same time

preserve the original one.

The 4th file must appear like this

```
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/12.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/20.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/21.mp3
625e8fd5f878b19b39826db539e01cda  mp3/19.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/5.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/7.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/10.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/8.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/3.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/2.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/1.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/11.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/6.mp3
7eac02c26935323fe167d6e39ef6bd0a  mp3/4.mp3
d7fbd596e86dfdb546092f34ab8ca576  mp3/25.mp3
```

Suggestions?Please don't answer : use fdup or external programs..I

prefer bash automation

Comment: Please format your question for readability and include your attempts so far.

Comment: I noticed that you have the same file path listed twice, meaning you could end up removing your only copy of mp3/25.mp3

Comment: If you don't want to use external programs why are you yourself using `find`, `awk`, `md5sum`, etc.? What is wrong with using a tool such as `fdupes`?

Comment: Also, paragraphs are a good thing. Please use them instead of this half sentence per line nonsense. And how many problems do you have? `grep -c 'Now the problem'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '{ if (seen[$1]++) print }' < file3 > file4
```

This builds up an awk array of the md5sums in column 1; if the array value for a particular md5sum has already been seen (e.g. *not* the first time it is seen), then it prints the line. Either way, it increments the array value for that md5sum, starting from the default of zero.

---

Another way, using bash associative arrays:

```bsh
unset md5sums
declare -A md5sums
while read md5sum path
do 
  ((md5sums[$md5sum]++))
  [[ ${md5sums[$md5sum]} -gt 1 ]] && printf "%s %s\n" "$md5sum" "$path" 
done < file3 > file4
```